# Show current method/block/region in Visual Studio plugin

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm sure I used to be able to see the name of the current class and method when editing vb.net files - I can't see anything similar in VS 2015 Update 3.

Does anyone know if there's a plugin that would show me this info? Being able to see the name of the current region would be brilliant, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> ensure that "Navigation bar" is checked. It doesn't display the region, just the class and method names.

Comment: @CodyGray Nice! Please make this an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plug-in; this feature is built into Visual Studio and has been since at least VS 2005. (Actually, it originated in the classic Visual Basic editor and was ported over to Visual Studio when the IDEs were integrated.) I'm not sure how it got disabled on your machine, since it is enabled by default.

Go to **Tools → Options → Text Editor → Basic** (or any language you want), and ensure that the **"Navigation bar"** option at the bottom is checked.

This will give you a bar at the top of your text editor window that displays the class and method names. It doesn't, however, display the region.

[image]

Comment: I've been looking for this feature for about a month before I finally decided to check StackOverflow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the current region in "Visual Assist" extension. 
You should download it from Nuget.(Tools --> Extension And Updates and then search the Visual Assist).
After you'll install it, You'll see a new tab called: "VA Outline" it's located near the Solution Explorer tab.

[image]

Comment: It does not show regions inside methods. And regions outside methods look bad (I mean expanded region in VAOutline is terrible)